# Does casting from Char to Int always give positive values in C

Tags: c, casting, integer, char, c-strings

I was writing production-ready C where I need to find the frequency of characters in a char array pretty fast. I was trying remove an assert call to check for positive values during a cast. Is my assert redundant code or is it necessary?

```
    char input[] = "Hello World";
    int inputLength = sizeof(input)/ sizeof(char);
    int *frequencies = calloc(256, sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < inputLength-1; i++)
    {
        int value = (int) input[i];
        assert(value > -1);//Is this line redundant?
        frequencies[value] += 1;
    }
    printf("(%d)", inputLength);
    PrintFrequencies(frequencies);
    free(frequencies);
```

Comment: The cast isn't necessary, and if the `char` is signed, you need the assertion.

Comment: Please note that `sizeof(char)` is specified to *always* be equal to `1`. Also note that the size of the array `input` will include the null-terminator. And that the result of the `sizeof` operator is a value of type `size_t`, for which you need the `%zu` format to print.

Comment: Perhaps you needed `int value = (unsigned char) input[i];` and then no assertion.

Comment: And for a small number like `256`, why not simply create a plain array? Like `unsigned frequencies[256] = { 0 };`? Note that I use the `unsigned` type since you can't have negative values in the array.

Comment: @WeatherVane Using a run-time `assert` that disappears entirely if compiled with `NDEBUG` defined is a horrible way to address this.  Whether `char` is signed or not is known at compile time.  Heck, just use `unsigned char`.

Comment: In your specific string, `"Hello World"`, all characters are non-negative, because any member of C’s basic character set has a nonnegative value, per C 2018 6.2.5 3. Other characters may have negative values. You can deal with that by casting an individual character value to `unsigned char`.  Also, the C standard allows there to be more than 256 possible values. You can accommodate that by changing the array size to `UCHAR_MAX+1`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Although there is the possibility of a machine having a 64 bit `char` type, such as the one I played with at University. Using `uint8_t` is probably the most sensible thing to do, although the machine I'm talking about probably wouldn't support it.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Using `unsigned char` and sizing the array with `UCHAR_MAX+1` gives a simple fully portable solution. Why bother making a solution that is technically less portable, even if rarely so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does casting from Char to Int always give positive values in C

Generally speaking, no.  `char` may be either a signed or an unsigned type, at the C implementation's discretion, but pretty frequently it is a signed type.

All `char` values representing members of the basic execution character set are guaranteed to be non-negative.  This includes the upper- and lowercase Latin letters, the decimal digits, a variety of punctuation, the space character and a few control characters.  The `char` values representing other characters may be negative, however. Also, the multiple `char` values constituting the representation of a multi-byte character can include some that, considered as individual `char`s, are negative.

> I was writing production-ready C where I need to find the frequency of characters in a char array pretty fast. I was trying remove an assert call to check for positive values during a cast. Is my assert redundant code or is it necessary?

Your `assert()` is semantically *wrong*.  If you're reading arbitrary text and you want your program to be robust, then you do need to be prepared for `char`s with negative values.  But

1. `assert`ions are the wrong tool for this job.  Assertions are for checking that the invariants your program assumes in fact hold.  You might use an assertion if you (thought you) had a guarantee that `char` values were always non-negative, for example.  If an assertion ever fails, it means your code is wrong.

   You must never use an assertion to validate input data or perform any other test that your program relies upon being performed, because depending on how you compile the program, the asserted expression might not be evaluated at all.
2. It would be better for your program to *handle* negative `char` values if they are encountered than to fail.  In this regard, do note that there's no particular use in converting your `char` explicitly to `int`.  You can use a `char` directly anywhere where you want an integer.  On the other hand, it might make sense to cast to `unsigned char`, as that will be cheap -- possibly free, even if `char` is signed -- and it will take care of your signedness problem.

Comment: lol are you the guy who invented bollinger bands? this is wild as hell

Comment: No, @muragekibicho, that's someone else. We're probably distantly related, but I couldn't tell you how.  Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Formally, there is no requirement that the values of the character sets supports by a standard C compiler have any particular value, positive or negative.

The `char` type can either by signed or unsigned: [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default). In situations where it is signed and some "extended character set" is implemented (beyond classic "7 bit ASCII" for example), then strings could in theory hold negative values.

So depending on how portable you need to code to be, there might be a place for the assert. However as mentioned in comments, casting to an unsigned type instead removes the problem. Consider using this instead:

```c
uint8_t value = input[i];
```

Now `value` is guaranteed to be in the range of 0 - 255 and the code is portable.

Answer (score 1):

For starters this statement

```
int inputLength = sizeof(input)/ sizeof(char);
```

is redundant. As the array contains a string when within the for loop you can just check whether a current character is the terminating zero character '`\0'`.

Also pay attention to that in general a character array can be much larger than the string stored in the array. So using this variable calculated such a way in general can be wrong. It would be more correctly to use standard C function `strlen` if the length of a stored string is required.
.
Using this casting

```
int value = (int) input[i];
```

is actually is equivalent to

```
int value = input[i];
```

due to the integer promotion.

The type `char` can behave either as the signed type `signed char` or as the unsigned type `unsigned char`.  To make the code independent on the behavior of the type `char` you need to cast each character to the type `unsigned char`.

So this assert

```
assert(value > -1);
```

does not useful.

An array with 256 elements of the type `int` is not very large. So you could define it with automatic storage duration. Also it will be logically consistent to use the type `unsigned int` instead of the signed type `int` in the array declaration.

Your code snippet can look like

```
char input[] = "Hello World";

unsigned int frequencies[256] = { 0 };

for ( const char *p = input; *p != '\0'; ++p )
{
    ++frequencies[( unsigned char )*p];
}

PrintFrequencies(frequencies);
```